# Atom text editor, command pallet transparent or move position

Tags: atom-editor, popupwindow

Is there Any way to make command pallet transparent or move from fixed position to bottom or right top in atom ?, since it is at exact middle of editor window unable to see exact usage of words(such as function, variables) in different files on click show usage.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, Atom is basically a web browser, so you can use JavaScript and CSS to manipulate its look and behaviour. You can use the [Developer Tools](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/#check-font-rendering-issues) to inspect and edit an element in realtime.

Once you familiarized yourself with these tools, you can add your own styles to your [user stylesheet](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#style-tweaks).

**Example:**

```
atom-panel.modal {
  float: left;

  &:before {
      opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer , but the movement i try to inspect the element to know  the class name  pop up is going away(i tried to add break point also ), I tried to know the class name  but i was not very sure what is the class name since it is a huge code base with lot of css.